# OpenLayersWidget & Django Admin Maps over Https

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mapping, geodjango

I'm still a novice Django/Python user, so apologies for the basic question.

I'm running into a problem where maps are not showing up in my Django admin. I was hoping to fix this problem by adding the `OpenLayersWidget` class to my `forms.py` project file, referenced in the Django docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/#django.contrib.gis.widgets.OpenLayersWidget. See below.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget

class OpenLayersWidget(forms.TextInput):
    """Specifying CDN of openlayers.js in the Media class."""

     class Media:
         js = (
             'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1',
         )
```

I'm sure this is too simplistic.

Unfortunately, the above does not work over https. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin as gis_admin

class SecureOSM(gis_admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    openlayers_url = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js'
```

Then inherit from here

**Update**

The https cloudflare url has become the default as of [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/admin/#django.contrib.gis.admin.GeoModelAdmin.openlayers_url). So patching should not be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need override the forms `Widget`. Example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets import BaseGeometryWidget

class CustomOpenLayersWidget(BaseGeometryWidget):
    template_name = 'gis/openlayers.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super(CustomOpenLayersWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    class Media:
        js = (
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js',
            'gis/js/OLMapWidget.js',
        )


class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Need to change default URL of OpenLayers"""
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.PointField: {"widget": CustomOpenLayersWidget},
        models.PointField: {"widget": CustomOpenLayersWidget},
        models.PolygonField: {"widget": CustomOpenLayersWidget},
        models.LineStringField: {"widget": CustomOpenLayersWidget},

        # Adding other models Fields if need
    }
```

and change the admin class

```
@admin.register(Position)
class PositionAdmin(CustomModelAdmin):
    pass
```

A example of model

```
class Position(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField(blank=False)
```

The code override field forms widgets to a new media itens. This remove http content `http://openlayers.org/api/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js` of media.